# Push notification not getting delivered via service workers

Tags: google-chrome, mobile, push-notification, service-worker, web-push

We have deployed the chrome service worker on our website in July 2015 and have over 380K active subscribers of which over 90% are mobile devices. 
But we are encountering issues with the service worker. When a user's cache gets cleared or  when many of the mobile apps like cleanmaster and other utility apps on a phone clear cache on a user's mobile.  In that case  we do not have any access to device token of that user. And hence even with 380K active users for which google sends us message ids we only get 50K impressions which is a very low ratio. 
Our push notification subscription is implemented on a seperate subdomain as we could not make the entire site https then.

I have 2 queries:

1. We would love to know if Google is working on setting up a canonical system (Which is there in GCM for mobile apps) through which even if the user's cache gets cleared via these apps he might be able to get push notifications. Our users have complained again and again that even after subscription they are not receiving push that's when we went deeper and figured this out.
2. Also is there a way through which we can ensure we get back those users ?

Comment: Could you provide details on what site this is? It could be a problem in your service worker code throwing an error meaning your "impressions" / analytics aren't accurate.

Answer (score 7):

When a user clears their cache in Chrome, it also unregisters service workers and clears the window cache as well. By unregistering the service workers it will unsubscribe the push subscriptions.

I agree that it's hard to understand the link between clearing a cache / cookies and how that relates to service worker and push notifications from the UI - the Chrome team are aware of this.

The best advice with respect to getting those users back is to ensure that when ever a user enables notifications and you get a subscription object, keep track of that decision as their last known decision and when the user re-visits your site, if they should be subscribed and you have permission, you can get a new subscription and send that back to your server.

### Update

I put together this blog post: https://gauntface.com/blog/2016/05/01/push-debugging-analytics

Looking at your site there are a few issues in your code:

- it seems that you have several broken promise chains and and overall it's hard to reason with what is going on in the push event, I'd strongly recommend tidying it up.
- There is a minor but obvious bug when the service worker start ups and tries to examine the push subscription, which doesn't exist.
- You are registering two service workers but only one of them gets used for push.

Checkout the blog post above, it covers how I came to that conclusion and some advice on how to fix it.

Comment: Is there anything in works that gives info on what happened to push notifications ? 
GCM has it in play console where exact journey of a push is given. 
We are getting message ids for most of the active subscribers but we are not getting impressions in analytics saying it reached the device. 

Can a system be built which explains what happened to push notification is given. 
Also can information be passed if there any cache clearing or anything that took away the device token of that device ? Would help in understanding how did the device tokens go away.

Comment: Right now our stats are 400K active subscribers for which we get valid message ids and only 50K impressions for the push.

Comment: I wonder if the issue is actually the push simply not being successfully delivered rather than cache clearing. I'm shooting in the dark now, but if you were to use the XMPP protocol for talking to GCM could you learn any more about when messages are/aren't being delivered? https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ccs

Comment: QQ from me: How you logging an "impression"? Is it an analytics that you set when the message is received? Or is it analytics for when the notification is clicked?

Comment: Also is it possible to get a link to the website this is concerning?

Comment: Can't I use https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268 for getting insights onto the push on service workers? I have added that in the play console. But when I put a message id its not showing any info

Comment: I don't think it is possible, it might be possible to figure out some hacky way of doing it, but I imagine it will ask for a package name that won't add up.

Comment: Hi Matt We have made the improvements that you had mentioned in the blog post. Interestingly it still hasn't resulted in improvements in impressions. We are logging all the dev IDs in the analytics console as well. The number doesn't cross 50k even when the push is active for 4 days. We right now have over 500k subscribers.

Comment: Also we noted when the browser is closed on a mobile device the push doesn't come for some devices. Noticed this with lenovo k4 note. We restarted the device, ensured the browser is closed (internet was connected) and tried sending a push to that particular device. The push didn't come

Comment: I just opened up your site again, I have the permission prompt to enable notifications come up mean while in the console I can see the message "Hi, subscriptionr received", multiple times. How can the subscription be received if it doesn't exist?

Comment: Things to note (1) Still see a lot of errors in the console. (2) the promise chains could be flattened rather than nested. Compare workingPromiseChain() and workingFlatPromiseChain() on the link in my blog post (3) You don't return on the first response.json() meaning your promise chain is still broken (4) Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: hdrPopShow is not defined
    at sendSubscriptionToServer (...)
    at ...

Comment: We have already rectified that. Can you give it a try once more ?

Comment: There are still a few issues and the subscription received message still concerns me given there is no subscription defined. http://imgur.com/QSWl7ma

Comment: Hi, We are getting subscription from 2 sub-domains. You have given permission to the first domain and checking it on 2nd domain. So, we are opening the first domain in iframe , so that in case of any cookie/cache clearance it sends the token back to server. Subscription received message corresponds to that first domain.

Thanks !

Comment: Slightly confused by what you mean. A push subscription for each subdomain would need permission in that case (And opening the URL loaded in the iframe instantly requests permission). I have granted zero permissions to either subdomains and yet it still logs that message.

Comment: Hi Matt
We did the inline thing as mentioned here in comment 5
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=605850#c5  We have 2 sub domains from which we are getting users subscribed. Earlier it was only on https://notify.buyhatke.com but a lot of our website traffic is to https://compare.buyhatke.com hence we also started taking it on all pages of https://compare.buyhatke.com     The iframe thing was implemented just to get the token of the user in case it has gotten erased and he is again visiting our website

Comment: Did you get a chance to check this Gaunt. We are also sometimes seeing latencies to when the device receives push to the tune of a couple of days even when the device was connected to the internet for about 20 hours in between from the time the push was sent and when it was received.

Also we now have 680K active subscribers and still we do not see delivery crossing 50K device ids. We are trying to resend to those users to whom the push did not reach

Comment: I'm sorry, until you fix the numerous errors in your web app, I'm not going to invest any further time debugging. Feel free to continue reaching out via the chrome issue, but I imagine engineers will also struggle to identify issues because there are so many errors from the minute you open the console.

Comment: Hi Matt 
We have rewritten the entire code and have resolved all promise chain issues. Right now you would not find any issue in the console for the same. Please have a look and guide further.

Comment: Did you get a chance to check this ?